# Time series forecasting using ARIMA

Tags: r, time, time-series

I am trying to forecast the future value of a variable. my data is

```
x <- structure(c(115, 209, 239, 264, 402, 769, 786, 922, 1205, 1671, 
22, 92, 126, 197, 215, 1118, 1120, 1546, 1677, 1697), .Tsp = c(1, 
2.9, 10), class = "ts")
```

The series has a frequency of 10. The series is integrated of the order three and based on `acf` and `pacf` the series is `(3,3,0)`. The answers that I am getting is not very encouraging as it doesn't reflect the trend. The next ten forecasted values are 1379,1240,736,156 and -588. Can anyone suggest why I might be getting this sort of answer?

Comment: This is a question about statistics, not programming. You should move it to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What are you using for forecasting? I would suggest using `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package. Assuming your time series called `myts`, try: `library(forecast) ; plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(myts, frequency = 10)), 10))`